# how to get Drive_FILE_ID using Google Drive android API

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

I am creating an application which uses user's Google Drive space to stores application's backup. As i am a beginner, i am having trouble understanding Google Drive android API.

I check several examples [android Quick Start](https://github.com/googledrive/android-quickstart)  and [Google Drive android API documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/files) but didn't got any proper solution.

My application simply needs to perform following operations-

- Create a file in a particular folder on Google Drive
- download that file for modification
- modify the content and then upload it back on Google Drive

Answer (score 0):

The getResourceId and getDriveId methods of Google Drive Android API are **Unpredictable**.

The resource id is not available until the newly created file is committed to the server so GoogleApiClient needs to be reconnected.